# Finding formulas for sequences, as well as boolean products.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm working on an assignment, and am not sure if I'm going about solving my problems the right way. Two of the problems are regarding sequences.

```
Find the formula for the sequences in terms of An, with the following first four terms:
1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5..., assume that the sequence begins with A1.
```

Going by an example given to me, I thought that the formula would be something like.

```
i = 1
while (i = n)
i = n + 1
return 1/i
n = n + 1
```

This starts the formula at A1, and then returns a value of 1/n+1, which is 1/2 for A1, 1/3, for A2, and so on.

The other formula problem is written as:

```
Imagine a sequence {An} where
A1 = 1, An+1 = 3An + 2^(n+1)
```

I have to find the closed formula of An. I figured this one is just as simple as the previous one, but since I'm not having difficulty, I have a feeling I'm going about it wrong. My answer is:

```
for n > 1
An = 3An+2^(A+1)
return An
```

I have another problem that I am fairly confident on, and that involves matrices.

```
Given matrices A, and B, find the join of A and B, the meet of A and B, and the Boolean product of A and B.

A: 1 0 1      B: 0 1 0
   0 1 1         0 1 1
   1 1 0         1 0 0
```

My answers are as follows:

```
Join: 1 1 1
      0 1 1
      1 1 0

Meet: 0 0 0
      0 1 1
      0 0 0

Boolean: 1 1 1
         0 1 1
         1 1 0
```

If my methods or answers are wrong, please let me know so that I can fix them and learn how to do it correctly!

Answer (score 0):

In the second, you got it wrong :

$$A_1 = 1$$
$$A_{n+1}=3A_n+2^{n+1}$$

It works as follows, you try to generate $A_1$,$A_2$,$A_3$... as much needed as possible to deduce the pattern :

SO :

$$A_1=1$$
\begin{align}
A_2 &= 3A_1+2^3 \\
   & =3 + 2^3
\end{align}
\begin{align*}
A_3 &= 3A_2+2^4\\
 & =3(3+2^3)+2^4\\
 & =3^2+3*2^3+2^4
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
A_4 & = 3A_3+2^5\\
 & =3(3^2+3*2^3+2^4)+2^5\\
 & =3^3+3^22^3+3*2^4+2^5\\
\end{align*}

that is enough to notice that general $A_n$ would be :

$$A_n = 3^{n-1} + \sum_{k=3}^{k=n+1}3^{n+1-k}*2^k$$
for $n=2, 3, 4...$

\begin{align*}
 f(x) &= (x+a)(x+b) \\
 &= x^2 + (a+b)x + ab
\end{align*}